# How do I make hierarchical permalinks/routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to route content in my Rails 3.2 app using a "friendly" permalink structure (as described in Adam Darowski's blog post[1](http://www.darowski.com/tracesofinspiration/2008/03/16/url-as-ui/)). I've found a few answers that describe how to do this within a single "pages" or "categories" controller, but ideally I would like the app to route to the most specific controller in cases of "partial" URLs.

```
http://example.com / shows / :genre / :series / :season / :episode
```

So, for example: `/shows/entertainment/the-survivors/01/01` would route to the Episodes controller (playing season 1 episode 1 of the particular series), and `/shows/entertainment/the-survivors/` would route to the Series controller (listing all the episodes in that series). And so forth.

I've heard the rule that nested routing should be no more than one level deep so that seems like a bad solution (and standard nested routing "pollutes" the URL with both controller names and IDs anyways like `/genres/entertainment/shows/the-survivors/seasons/1/episodes/1`, which I'd like to avoid).

The best solution I've been able to figure out so far is just a series of increasingly specific `match` rules in my routes.rb file which point to each controller as the URL gets more and more specific.

Is there any better way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a friendly url gem like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).  I'd get rid of the "shows" part of your url unless that specifically adds something to the routing.  Then you could make urls like:

```
/entertainment/the-survivors/s01e01
```

and just find each series and episode by slug ('the-survivors' and 's01e01' respectively).

I think either way you are going to have to create custom routes in your route file like you mention in your question, however I don't see a problem with that.

I do however disagree with your idea of creating two controllers.  In your question you mention that it

> would route to the Series controller (listing all the episodes in that series)

In your language you are saying "listing all the episodes".  The episodes are the resource so if you are being truly [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services), then the "series" page as such should be the `index` action of the `EpisodesController`, with each episode being the `show` action of the `EpisodesController`.